# Processing.js BACKSPACE is not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, processing.js, backspace

Somehow this processing.js code doesn't work in Chrome but works in Safari and Firefox:

```
void keyPressed() {
 if(key == BACKSPACE) {
   println("BACKSPACE was pressed"); 
 } 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Chrome version: 24.0.1312.52 | Safari version 6.0.2 | Firefox version 17

Mac OS 10.8.2

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, "backspace" is the hotkey for "previous page". Rather than sending the key to the element you're focussed on, the document hijacks the key and tries to switch page contexts upon seeing it pressed.

If you want your sketch to accept the backspace, you'll first have to make sure it's trapped using something like http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/pages/KeyTrap

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. Doesn't work. 
I mean it works as described in this API -- even outputs the message that "key '8' got trapped in element with id 'MyProcessingScetch' " -- Only now not only Chrome can't see it, but any other browser including Safari.

Comment: I just thought that KeyTrap might work if I communicate with the sketch 
using KeyTrap callback function. Meaning I would pass my sketch some variable 
(like for example backspaceVar = true). And in the sketch I'd just say if(backspaceVar) {
   println("BACKSPACE was pressed"); 
} 
Need to try this.

Comment: That might work. I try to steer clear of using the backspace button myself, and any other established browser buttons like alt+cursor and ctrl-r... they're dangerous keys to rely on.

Comment: Kinda hard if you are writing a typography/text editor... : )

Comment: not that hard for a typography editor (which would be about typesetting, backspace strictly speaking not used, delete would be). For a text editor... honestly, not much sense in using Processing. Especially on the web, since it runs in HTML context already. And I say that both as one of the Pjs developers, and as someone who wrote font parsers and character compositors =)